# SVN: Create branch from earlier revision, then apply specific revisions

Tags: svn, branch

I have an `SVN` branch that I would like to branch again. However, I would like this new branch to be a copy of the source branch at a revision before `HEAD`. I would then like to apply an arbitrary set of revisions to this new branch after it's created.

For example, the `HEAD` revision on the branch that I want to branch again is 10. I want to copy this branch at revision 5, then apply revisions 7 and 9 to the new branch.

I know I can accomplish the first part with `svn copy -r5 source target`, but how do I apply revisions 7 and 9 to *target*?

I'm using the `SVN` command line client, not Tortoise or any other GUI-based client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [SVNBook | Advanced Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html).

[Cherrypick merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking) should work in your case. Note that some of the examples specify `--change (-c)` instead of `--revision`.

1. Checkout a clean working copy of the target branch:

   `svn checkout TARGET-URL WCPATH`
2. Merge changes introduced by revisions 7 and 9 in SOURCE branch to the working copy.

   `svn merge SOURCE-URL -c7,9 WCPATH`
3. Carefully examine the merge results and `svn commit` the result.